# Google Earth adds random black rectangles to my transparent png overlay - how to avoid this in either png creation or kml?

Tags: kml, google-earth

Viewing the PNG in an image viewer, it is normal.
Viewing the PNG as an overlay in Google Earth, random black rectangles are added near the transparent regions of the image.
How to avoid this in either PNG generation or in KML?
The PNG is BufferedImage.TYPE_4BYTE_ABGR

Comment: This a screen or ground overlay? I have similar issues with transparent legends ([example](http://imgur.com/TbgBo)).  Notice borders of icons not extending to/extending past border. No scaling and correct if png opened in viewer.  Same distortion if put as ground overlay as well.